# Why Was the DM CFO in Charge of Discipline and Branch Visits?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-office

In The Office (US), we see David Wallace come to Dunder-Mifflin Scranton to talk directly to the branch employees or Michael directly. Either for discipline or some initiative they are doing, or calling Michael directly to discuss a company policy or some new idea Michael had but pawned off on Dwight.

We also see Michael (and a few times Dwight) go to corporate in NYC to face disciplinary hearings with David or interview with David for a corporate position and so on.

My question is: why (in-universe) would Dunder-Mifflin have the company **CFO** doing those tasks. It wasn’t a massive international company but every corporation I’ve worked for has never had c-suite directly interact with people to that level. That’s what executive admins, hiring managers, and regional directors are for.

Isn’t David’s job to focus solely on the financials and the only reports he should be hearing are the quarterly reports meetings from Michael and the other branch managers?

Comment: I’ve worked for someone answerable to the CFO before but that’s because I was in IT and because older companies had computers in finance first, sometimes IT is still under finance. Perhaps in the case of DM it’s a sales and revenue focused business so sales is under finance? It could also be part of the overall atmosphere of corporate incompetence.

Comment: @ToddWilcox that’s one thing I considered too. That the top brass was so horribly disorganized, they had the CFO doing the job of a sales director alongside his financial duties. I’m guessing that’s what Jan’s job used to be before they apparently nixed it during the Sabre merger. Charles Minor was the last one to fill that role but he dropped out of sight after the picnic episode. In the post-Sabre DM, it looks like David decided not to fill that role.